# How to not make text colored within a href link but the text is also within div?

Tags: html, css, colors

How can I make text NOT blue colored when I make entire div as a link?

So in the following snippet:

```
<a href="/link"><div><h2>LINK</h2></div></a>
```

I want to make the entire `div` be linked to another page, but also don't want to get the string `LINK` as blue colored as is the case with usual linking object.

When I wrote the following CSS:

```
a {text-decoration: none; background-color: none; }
```

it didn't change at all.

[Update]

Thanks for many answers. The reason I want to put `div` inside `a` is that I want to make the block linkable object (click on the block and go to another page). I first put `a` inside `div`, but it didn't work, and that's why I put it outside `div`. (and I use HTML5 and CSS3).

Comment: Don't use `div`'s in `a`'s.

Comment: U didnt use color:bla bla; so it would show blue color :|

Comment: html5 allows block-elements inside links...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In HTML 5, easily use this:

```
<a href="/yourLinkAddress">
    <div class="link">
         <h2>Link Text</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link
{
   color:aqua;
   text-decoration: none; 
   background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: @IvanAracki add `.link:hover{text-decoration:none}` to get it without underline.

Answer (score 4):

You are **allowed** to use divs/block-elements inside links in html5 specs, so that's not nessesarily bad.

Background means what's behind the text, that is behind this code below is gray. Color is what you are after..

```
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: black; 
}
```

## Edit: Sources:

- [Are block-level elements allowed inside inline-level elements in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5)

Goto: http://validator.w3.org/check and validate this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#stuff">
        <div>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<a href="/link"><div class="link"><h2>LINK</h2></div></a>
```

then apply class:

```
.link{
  background-color:none;
  color:blue;
 }
```

If you are not permitted to use  inside  tags then try using table instead of . It should work in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Simply target **h2**

```
a div h2 {
    color: #fff; /*Or whatever you want*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**css:**

```
.link
{
  text-decoration: underline;
color: #0000EE;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<strong>Hello!</strong> you have already registered , you can login
<a href="http://www.example.com/"><span class="link">here</span></a>
```

**reference:**

[default HTML/CSS link color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color) and [this](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks02.htm)

[Wikipedia Link Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Link_color) lists different link color and their meanings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
a{text-decoration: none; background-color: none;color:gray; }
```

//for color-give your desired color..

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration: none;` doesn't effect with accepted answer!

**This is your code**

```
<a href="/link"><div><h2>LINK</h2></div></a>
```

**Correct is;**

```
<div class='editLink'> 
     <a href="/link">
       <h2>LINK</h2> 
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editLink a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed to use `div` in `a` ([in html5 allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)):

HTML before 5:

```
<h2><a href="/link" class="link">LINK </a></h2>
```

HTML5:

```
<a href="/link" class="link"><h2>LINK</h2></a>
```

CSS:

```
.link
 {
  color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use `div` within `a` ([you can in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)),You can use this instead:

```
<a href="/link" style="color:green;">LINK</a>
```