# Make element same color as default anchor link

Tags: css

Is it possible to use CSS to make an element the same color as the default `<a>` color?

If so, how?

Comment: element {color:blue; }  does this not working ?

Comment: @GCyrillus: The default `a` color isn't really `blue`, though. Not in every browser anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock right, depends too on a, a:link,a:visited :)

Comment: I think I will probably need to pick a "default" color for links, and assign them to both the normal links and my desired elements.  I will probably use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color as the defaults.

Comment: There is only a solution is to wrap your element by a fake `a` element.

Comment: Not without using JavaScript, so far as I'm aware (and even then it's likely to be the 'default colour' as interpreted/affected by CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no keyword to specify a color as the same color of a link (although we does have keywords to specify **system colors**). There is only a workaround is using a script to build some CSS rule styling the color the same as of a link and use this style for your element.

```
//Get the default link color in the current browser
var a = $("<a href='#'>").appendTo('body');
var linkColor = a.css('color');
a.remove();
//build the CSS rule 
var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
if('addRule' in ss) {
  ss.addRule(".defaultLinkColor", "color: " + linkColor);
} else if('insertRule' in ss){
  ss.insertRule(".defaultLinkColor { color: " + linkColor + ";}", 0);  
}
```

Then you can apply the class `defaultLinkColor` for your element:

```
<span class='defaultLinkColor'>I'm not a link</span>
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/sza3q/1/)

Comment: Interesting approach.  Works in Chrome, but not FF29

Comment: @user1032531 it's because `FF` does not (maybe **never**) support `addRule` method, it supports only the `insertRule` method. I updated the code as well as the demo.

Comment: That's because `addRule()` is non-standard. Presumably Chrome supports it in addition to `insertRule()` for interop reasons.

Comment: A simpler cross-browser way (when you are using jQuery anyway) is to set the property directly on the elements: `$('.defaultLinkColor').css('color', linkColor);`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yes, but it works in a different way, any newly created element should have style changed with that line of code.

Comment: I like the add/insert rule approach more since it better allows for added elements.  Before seeing your edited post, I was playing with the same thing, but kept getting `SecurityError: The operation is insecure. ss.insertRule(".defaultLinkColor { color: " + linkColor + ";}", 0);` error.  I think your version well (note that your demo link is broken).  Thank you

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: FYI, I just reopened [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color) and updated my answer with some new findings based on your comment. I can't think of a good way to edit the question into something that's at least worth all the upvotes it has received over time, but it is on-topic nonetheless.