# How to set the color to the user's link color in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I would like to have a an element use the same color the browser uses for unvisited links by default. How would I do that?

```
<div style="color:???">This should have the same color</div>
<a href=".">as this!</a>
```

Furthermore, it should work in older browsers, too, if possible. JavaScript is possible.

Comment: should user select the color, using a color picker?

Comment: @Trix — Some browsers have a preference option which allows the user to select a default colour for links.

Comment: No, there is no interaction with the user. I'd simply like to copy the color that the browser currently uses by default.

Comment: You want to apply it to div or hyperlinks only?

Comment: @pratikwebdev A single div - I don't want to change regular hyperlinks

Comment: check my updated answer. It works fine as wanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make element same color as default anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456300/make-element-same-color-as-default-anchor-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```js
var colored = document.getElementsByClassName('colored')[0];
style = window.getComputedStyle( document.querySelector( '.links' ), ':link'),
color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
colored.style.color = color;
```

```css
a:link{
  color: #FF5656;
}
```

```html
<div class="colored" style="color:???">This should have the same color</div>
<a class="links" href="">as this!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, something like [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword) can do this, but in this case you need inheritance, so I've wrapped the `div` and `a`

> The `currentColor` keyword represents the calculated value of the
>   element's `color` property. It allows to make the color properties
>   inherited by properties or child's element properties that do not
>   inherit it by default.
>
> It can also be used on properties that inherit the calculated value of
>   the element's `color` property and will be equivalent to the inherit
>   keyword on these elements, if any.

#### Snippet

```css
#parent {
  color: red
}
a:link,.child {
  color: currentColor
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a href="#">This will be red</a>
  <div class="child">This will have the same color has the link</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's inheriting the explicitly specified colour of the  *body* (which you've happened to make the same as the link), it isn't using the *default* colour of the link.

Comment: yup I am aware that `currentColor` doesn't work with siblings only with parents/childs, but using `body` here was just a demo, I could've wrap this and give the red color to that parent. this is just a CSS solution only if OP wants.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I guess now makes a little more sense.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, would this also work if you did not set the color of the parent node?

Comment: @mafu `currentColor` needs to be inherited therefore a parent in my snippet above.  you can see some examples [here](https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/)

Answer (score 0):

Two simple methods:

Method 1: using `<a>` tag. Just use the `<a>` tag as you use it for hyperlinks but without "href". `<div>` tag depends upon your program.

```html
<div><a>This should have the same color</a><div>
<a href="#">as this!</a>
```

Method 2: using css.

```css
            .SameColor {
              color: #0000EE;
            }
```

```html
<div class="SameColor">This should have the same</div>
<a href="#">as this!</a>
```

Comment: Method 1 won't work. Browsers do not give the same default styling to an anchor which isn't any kind of link as they do to one which is is an unvisited link.

Comment: Method 2 won't work. You are hard coding the colour instead of using whatever the browser is set to use by default for unvisited links.