# How do I inspect the exact default CSS coloring schemes for a browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, colors

Noob question: How do I find out the default coloring (hex/rbg) directly from a browser inspector, if possible? @BoltClock♦'s answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color) mentions "the about:blank technique" "to sniff out the default colors"--what exactly is that technique?

I'm trying to determine the default `:focus` blue border color for `textarea` using the Chrome developer tool. After some digging, I found `outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color` which isn't too useful... so I had to Google for the actual color (#5B9DD9 according to [this](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/)). 
[image: inspecting element on textarea for default color]

Comment: According to [this](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/) it's #5B9DD9.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the "inspect element" on chrome?
Basically, you right click on the thing you want to find the coloring of, and select "inspect element".

Then a box will pop up with two boxes inside of it. Whatever html(div or text) you've got selected in the left box will have it's css properties appear in the right. You might have to scroll a little, if it doesn't appear right at the top. The color should be there.