# Inherit takes the body properties

Tags: inheritance

This is my html flow:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="action">Send</button>
  <input type="submit" class="action" />
  <a href="" class="action more-link">More</a>
</div>

css:
     body{
        font-family:arial;
        color:#444;
    }
    a{
        color:#2C7EC7;
        text-decoration:none;   
    }
    .container{
        width:900px;
        padding:15px;
        margin:0 auto;  
    }
    .action{
        margin:0 15px;
        padding:5px 10px;
        border:0 none;
        outline:none;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size:14px;
        background:#5F5F5F;
    }
    a.more-link{
        padding:0;
        background:none;    
        color:inherit;
    }
```

the more-link not taking the color of default anchor tag which am using in my theme. or what should i do to set the default anchor color to any other classes which is set to be in anchor tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color

Comment: Thank you :) . But am not asking about the browser default color value for the anchor tag. i need to set a color to anchor tag and i need to inherit the value to where ever i want in the css. for ex: <a href="link1"></a> for this class i am not allowed to use any color value but i need to get the color value of the anchor which i set to top of my css.

Comment: not sure what u want... is this something you can work with? https://jsfiddle.net/9s39ugux/5/