# how do i make a heading a hyper link without changing it's style in css

Tags: html, css

I tried attaching a link to my heading but i ended up having the style of the text formatted. What did i do wrong

```css
h2 {
  color: green;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="#">Sign in</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solutions :

```css
h2{
    color:green;
    text-align: right;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    text-decoration: none;

}
a{
 color:green;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
   <h2> <a href="#">Sign IN</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `inherit` here to save setting the same color etc twice.

[**Links have default colors**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color) depending on their states which have to be overridden.

```css
h2 {
  color: green;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="#">Sign in</a></h2>
```

or even...`currentColor`..

```css
h2 {
  color: green;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 a {
  color: currentColor;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="#">Sign in</a></h2>
```