# Is there a way to unset an 'a' tag link to the default color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have an 'a' tag that is a normal link to another webpage.

I want to disable the default link appearance unless the mouse cursor is hovering over the link, when the default normal link appearance should be restored.

This is what I have tried so far:

(HTML)

```
   <a href="example.com">example</a>
```

(CSS)

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: unset;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[JS fiddle example of that code here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ujkpyax/)

The problem is that during the mouse hover the link color remains black, and does not unset or restore to the original link blue.  Is there a special CSS keyword for "original setting" or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [value for original setting you're looking for](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp) is called `initial`.

```
a:hover {
    color: initial
}
```

However, that might make the link black. Which means it wouldn't work for you in this case. **You can get around this another way though,** through your `a` style. Use the inverse of `:hover` using the `:not` selector.

```css
a:not(:hover){
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hi, I'm Link.</a>
```

The way it works is applying the style to your link, as long as it's not the hover effect. `a` alone would style the `:hover` too, which we don't want.

Or if that doesn't work in your environment, you could style the link with the [default colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color):

```css
a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }

a:hover {color: #0000EE; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<a href="#">Hi, I'm Link.</a>
```

That should work everywhere, as it's a regular color change. However, do note that the default color might slightly vary browser to browser... the perk of this is that the color stays the same across all browsers, I guess.

The difference between the middle and last piece of code is that the middle one uses the default browser settings, while the last one pushes in your own blue.

Comment: That not(:hover) is clever, @Martin, that does the trick.  My thought was to support user style sheets, which I now realize have not been supported in Chrome since v33, though there are extensions that reenable the functionality.  Thanks!