# changing text color of an anchor element inside a nav element

Tags: html, css

```
  <nav>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
    <a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
    <a href="#">VENUE</a>
    <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
  </nav>
```

when i target the 'nav' element in CSS, I am able to change properties such as the font-size/font-weight/letter-spacing of the content of the 'a' element. However, I cannot change the text color. In order to do so, I have to target 'nav a'.

Why am I able to target some typographical properties when specifying just 'nav' but not others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [child tag does not inherit the style of a parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#inherited_properties), when it has its own style.

`a` tag has a default style:

```css
a: -webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Therefore, you should use more specific the selector

Answer (score 1):

[`href's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) or hyperlinks have [custom browser styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774022/whats-default-html-css-link-color#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20official%20default,no%20defined%20default%20link%20color.) including text color. Hence, is why you have to specify a specific color to override the default.

```css
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
  <a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
  <a href="#">VENUE</a>
  <a href="#">REGISTER</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because  has a default font color, it does not inherit the parent element's font color.